# What happened when the program return but without free the allocated memory?

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks

I'm thinking about the problem that if I allocate a block of memory to a program while without free it before the program ends. The memory whether can be reallocated? or do I have any ways to free that leaked memory so that it can be used again? Does C or C++ support the free function automatically?

Comment: When the program ends, all the memory is reclaimed by the operating system.

Comment: Stop thinking and test it:)  write a short app that allocates a meg and does not free it.  Run it continually from a batch file loop.  Leave it all running over a weekend.  On Monday, inspect your system to see if anything notable has happened.